# Members of "Remote Desktop Users" group cannot logon to Windows Server 2019 domain controller

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2019, remote-desktop-services

I installed a Windows 2019 domain controller. I added a user to the Remote Desktop Users group. The user cannot logon to the server, unless I add them to the Administrators group.

All I see in other answers here are to do just that (or to create a local user - which is not possible on a DC - only a standalone server).

How do I configure a Windows Server 2019 domain controller to allow a domain user account, to logon to the server using remote desktop?

I am unable to find a method and don't see any default policies for RDP anywhere. Perhaps I didn't install something when setting it up?

For years I've set up remote users, but never to a DC, so I'm not sure how to proceed as the obvious adding of users to RDP group doesn't work.

Comment: You don't mention whether you have purchased the Terminal Services license. You need TS in order to allow non-administrators to remote in to your server.

Comment: I have 25 CALs. I thought TSLs came with CALs (my ignorance)

Comment: There's supposed to be a 120 day grace period - I just built the thing.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-client-access-license

Comment: oops - the grace period is only for device CALs

Comment: tsc_chazz, put your comment in as the answer. I can't believe I forgot about TS (but never had to use it until now after 20 years).

Comment: Done, and thank you for your consideration... and that one bit me too, years ago, which is why I remember it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the Terminal Services add-on, a Windows 2019 server only has remote access available to administrators. In order to get non-administrative users to have RDP access, you have to purchase the TS add on and CALs for the users who will be connecting remotely.